# Calling .Net unmanaged code from Delphi code

Tags: .net, delphi

Delphi contains many types in its decelerations
Type 
  Record

Type 
   Instance

Type 
  Class

They ether contain a layout of a structure, or a group of methods or a Class that contains both. DotNet contains many of these objects as unmanaged code just as you declare Delphi decelerations but they are accessed through DLL’s. 
1/ The question is do you use TComObjectfactroy to access a deceleration in external DLL’s? Or do you use something else. I have no material to even read on the subject.

2/ I know you can get the object pointer (Class pointer) with a create method as it’s cleared with FreeAndNil as a pointer. How can you use create into a DLL containing a object.

3/ I have .Net ilasm.exe and ildasm.exe and a Delphi asm decompiler that I wish to find the main DLL in P/Invoke and place P/Invoke code into Delphi code.

But I have to understand Delphi objects in this way.
Has any one read or seen anything that comes near to this subject?
Until now I have not got subject matter correct that people can begin to understand me.

Juliano 117 gave me http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx
But thai is the Windows end!!!!!!! And not Delphi end.

Comment: @lexdean: I know that you've heard this before, but stop creating new accounts for every question.  Your credibility drops, and after a while the SO-user wouldn't bother to answer your questions...

Answer (score 0):

For information about the Delphi object model and the memory layout of classes, I belive that this chapter in the book "Delphi in a Nutshell" can give you some good information:

http://oreilly.com/catalog/delphi/chapter/ch02.html

Rudy Velthuis has also written an excellent article about this topic:

http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html

*It is, however, not recommended to pass classes between a dll and exe.*

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to combine managed .NET code and unmanaged native Delphi code in the same project, then you should have a look at [RemObjects Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/).
This is a framework for generating plugins that will make this work a lot easier.